# Target nested td inside a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table which contains a nested table inside as follows:

What I want to achieve this to target the `td` inside the nested table, and put values on a button click. Can someone please help me on how to target this in jquery ?

```
<table class="mdl-data-table" style=" width: 100%; ">
  <tr>
    <td>Text </td>
    <td>
      <table class="mdl-data-table ">
        <tr>
          <td> Name: </td>
          <td> </td> -- target content here
          <td> Age : </td>
          <td> </td> -- target content here
        </tr>
      </table>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$( "td:eq( 1 )" )` and `$( "td:eq( 3 )" )`

Comment: Where's the button in your HTML? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.mdl-data-table .mdl-data-table tr:first td:odd')
```

This will target the second and fourth `td`s of your table's first row.

**Working demo:**

```js
$('.mdl-data-table .mdl-data-table tr:first td:odd')
  .each(function() {
    $(this).text('test');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mdl-data-table" style=" width: 100%; ">
  <tr>
    <td>Text </td>
    <td>
      <table class="mdl-data-table ">
        <tr>
          <td> Name: </td>
          <td> </td> -- target content here
          <td> Age : </td>
          <td> </td> -- target content here
        </tr>
      </table>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.has](https://api.jquery.com/has/) then find the specific td.

```js
console.log($( "td" ).has( "table" ).find("td:eq(1)").text())
console.log($( "td" ).has( "table" ).find("td:eq(3)").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mdl-data-table" style=" width: 100%;" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Text </td>
    <td>
      <table class="mdl-data-table ">
        <tr>
          <td> Name: </td>
          <td> -- target content here 1 </td>
          <td> Age : </td>
          <td> -- target content here 2</td> 
        </tr>
      </table>
  </tr>
</table>
```